# How can isoclines show a solution to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have this differential equation:

> $$y'= 2x + y$$

Now, the isoclines are:

> $$2x + y = m \implies y = m - 2x$$

How can I deduce the solution to this differential equation based on this?

I got this from the MIT OCW, here is the question (it's the second problem):
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/geometric-methods/MIT18_03SCF11_ps1_s2s.pdf

But the explanation of the solution makes no sense to me, I don't understand at all why are the isoclines of m=2 are the solution.

Comment: Look at the question closely - it wants a $y_1(x)$ that solves the differential equation such that the trajectory is *also* an isocline. Thus, a trajectory of the form $y_1(x) = -2x + m$. This forces $y'_1 = -2$, and on feeding it into the ODE, the only such trajectory possible is $y_1(x) = -2x -2$.

Comment: They are asking for a solution that is an isocline.

Comment: I get it now. I just couldn't figure out the flow of the ideas in the given solution. Thank you!